# Most general unifier for set of equations?

Tags: logic, algorithms, computer-science, first-order-logic, unification

Find the MGU in the following set of expressions

$bar(1,Y,X,Y),bar(X,X,1,Z),bar(1,g(Y),1,f(W))$

Attempt

I do not know if you can work with the 3 functions at the same time. So I did for 2 functions first. So consider (1) and (2) $bar(1,Y,X,Y),bar(X,X,1,Z)$ first.

Using 
Algorithm 10.15  I found that MGU $\theta\ is\ \{X\leftarrow1,Y\leftarrow1,Z\leftarrow1\}$.

Then I considered (2) and (3) $bar(X,X,1,Z),bar(1,g(Y),1,f(W))$

Applying $\theta$ in (2) yields

$$1=1\\ 1=g(Y)\\ 1=1\\ 1=f(W)$$ which implies by the Algorithm $$1=g(Y)\\ 1=f(W)$$

But in this equations you cannot apply the algorithm, hence can we conclude that MGU does not exist?

Or what can be done here?

---

Algorithm 10.15 (Unification algorithm) (See Ben-Ari page 190)

Input: A set of term equations.

Output: A set of term equations in solved form or report not unifiable.

Perform the following transformations on the set of equations as long as any one
of them is applicable:

1. Transform $t = x$, where $t$ is not a variable, to $x = t$.
2. Erase the equation $x = x$.
3. Let $t = t'$ be an equation where $t$, $t'$  are not variables.

   - If the outermost function symbols of $t$ and $t'$ are not identical, terminate the algorithm and report not unifiable.
   - Otherwise, replace the equation $f (t_1, \dots , t_k) = f (t_1' , \dots , t_k')$ by the $k$ equations $t_1 = t_1' , \dots , t_k = t_k'$.
4. Let $x = t$ be an equation such that $x$ has another occurrence in the set.

   - If $x$ occurs in $t$ and $x$ differs from $t$, terminate the algorithm and report not unifiable.
   - Otherwise, transform the set by replacing all occurrences of $x$ in other equations by $t$.

Comment: It may be that if you'd tell us what "most general unifier" means we'd have a better chance of helping out.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Basically is a substitution, you need to apply the algorithm in all the equations to find the most general substitution

Comment: Yes, I would agree with your observation. Since there are no axioms on f and g, you cannot find an unifying substitution

Comment: @AgnishomChattopadhyay ok, thank you.

Comment: If I read correctly, $bar$ is a relation symbol, and you are asked to unify three atoms.  If you observe that you would have to unify $Y$ and $g(Y)$, which is not possible, you immediately conclude that there is no MGU for the three given atoms.  (The impossibility of unification of $Y$ and $g(Y)$ is the first bullet of Step 4 of the algorithm you cite.)

Comment: @FabioSomenzi you're right I did see it, It would have saved lot of my time.. thanks!